# How I search datasets by multiple tags using CKAN API?

Tags: postgresql, api, solr, ckan

I'm using CKAN portal with API version "ckan_version": "2.5.x"
I have few tags and I need to send using API these tags
and I need to return a list of matching entries of packages or resources.

Is possible to use do use package_search endpoint to search for packages with all given tags, but it works as "AND" operator, and that I need is a "OR" operator.
e.g.:

- http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_search?fq=tags:contabilidade-social
  <-- return 11 packages that contains 'contabilidade-social'
- http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_search?fq=tags:contabilidade-social+governo
  <-- return 11 packages that contains 'contabilidade-social' and 'governo'
- http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_search?fq=tags:contabilidade-social+governo+enogastronomia <-- return 0 packages that contains 'contabilidade-social' and 'governo'and 'enogastronomia'. For my purpose it should return matches with 'OR' operator instead.

PS: I used top 10 tags (http://demo.ckan.org/api/action/package_search?facet.field=[%22tags%22]&facet.limit=10&rows=0).

I think it have relation with SOLR and postgresql index. 
There is a way to do that? If not, Is possible to extend or create a facet that make possible  use this kind of search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following syntax:

```
fq=tags:(tag1 OR tag2 OR tag3)
```

For instance:

http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/package_search?fq=tags:(contabilidade-social%20OR%20governo%20OR%20enogastronomia)

Comment: If you tag has white space  you must  put double quotes  e.g. "tag1 and more" .

Answer (score 0):

If not using the API, then entering the search words separated by | and no spaces seems to work e.g. blue|red would return datasets with blue or red. e.g.  dark blue|red also seems to work if one of the terms has a space in it.