# CKAN: specifying tags in search box?

Tags: search, tags, ckan

We use CKAN as open data portal software. The search engine is powered by Solr.

When using the API for searches [tags can be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568242/how-i-search-datasets-by-multiple-tags-using-ckan-api).

Is it possible to enter tags in the search box and make a search exclusively for tags?

I tried to enter

```
tags:(tag1 OR tag2)
```

and this seems to work. But is this feature supported and mentioned in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to limit the dataset search you can use faceted search by using the tags. When you search with tags, CKAN will use fq(filter query) to restrict the superset of data returned. Check this Search API call example [Tags](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/api/index.html?highlight=fq#tags-not-in-a-vocabulary). Also, you can check the search settings [configuration](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/configuration.html?highlight=search#search-settings). You can also customize the search facets by using [IFacets interface](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IFacets).